# jQuery extracting attributes from xml document

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm a javascript / JQuery newbie, so I hope this is obvious to you guys.
I'm trying to implement javascript / JQuery based translation of html documents.
Given this xml document with translations:

```
<definitions>
  <parameters>
    <parameter name="misc.gain" caption="Gain"/>
    <parameter name="misc.integral" caption="Integration time"/>
  </parameters>
</definitions>
```

In my script, I have found an element that needs to be translated.
The above document is in xlmdocument.

```
var my_id = $( this ).attr('id');  // ="misc.gain" on first iteration
// find xml node whose name is = my_id from xmldocument
// extract caption attribute from xml node
$( this ).html( translatedcaption); //
```

Can someone give me a hint, I'm kind of stuck here.

Edit :
A nice guy provided me with hint and direction, don't know why he deleted his post.

My final solution was:

```
   var my_id = $( this ).attr('id');
   var xmlnode = $(xmldocument).find("parameter[name='" + my_id + "']");
   $( this ).html($(xmlnode).attr("caption"));
```

Thanks for your quick help Mr. X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice guy provided me with hint and direction, don't know why he deleted his post.

My final solution was:

```
   var my_id = $( this ).attr('id');
   var xmlnode = $(xmldocument).find("parameter[name='" + my_id + "']");
   $( this ).html($(xmlnode).attr("caption"));
```

Thanks for your quick help Mr. X